# Subclass not initialising parent class in Python 2.x

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm having some problems initialising the parent class inside one subclass in Python 2. What I'm trying to do is override parent class attributes with properties in the child class.

Somehow, when I don't use the method `_update_rect(self)` in the child class setters (e.g. `_set_grab(self, ps_value)` and `_set_grab(self, ps_value)`), everything works as expected. But as soon as I use it the initialization of the parent class fails (the `print '+++ END GfxObject initialisation'` is not reached) and I get `AttributeError: 'GfxRect' object has no attribute '_s_grab'`.

As I said at the beginning, the code looks correct to me and the problematic method `_update_rect` only uses real attributes of itself so I have no idea where the error comes. I could avoid using inheritance in the child class as a workaround but I really want to understand what the problem is.

Regards and thanks in advance.

```
# Extra code to simplify test code
#=================================
class pygame:
    class Rect:
        def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.w = w
            self.h = h


# Classes
#========
class GfxObject(object):
    """
    Generic Graphical Object which is the parent class of all the sub-classes below.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.i_x = 0
        self.i_y = 0
        self.s_grab = 'nw'


class GfxRect(GfxObject):
    """
    Class to draw a rectangle.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        print '--- START GfxObject initialisation'
        super(GfxRect, self).__init__()
        print '+++ END GfxObject initialisation'

        self._i_x = 0
        self._s_grab = 'nw'
        self._o_rect = None

        print self

        self._update_rect()

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        u_out = u'<GfxRect>\n'
        u_out += u'  .i_x:     %s\n' % self.i_x
        u_out += u'  ._i_x:    %s\n' % self._i_x
        u_out += u'  .s_grab:  %s\n' % self.s_grab
        u_out += u'  ._s_grab: %s\n' % self._s_grab
        return u_out

    def _get_grab(self):
        return self._s_grab

    def _get_x(self):
        return self._i_x

    def _set_grab(self, ps_value):
        self._s_grab = ps_value
        #self._update_rect()
        self._b_redraw = True

    def _set_x(self, i_value):
        self._i_x = i_value
        self._update_rect()
        self._b_redraw = True

    def _update_rect(self):
        """
        Method to update the pygame rectangle object.
        :return:
        """

        # [1/?] Calculating the deltas for (x,y) based on the grab position
        #------------------------------------------------------------------
        if self._s_grab == 'nw':
            i_dx = 0
        elif self._s_grab == 'n':
            i_dx = -800 / 2
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid grab value "%s"' % self._s_grab)

        # [2/?] Applying the deltas
        #--------------------------
        i_x = self._i_x + i_dx

        self._o_rect = pygame.Rect(i_x, 0, 800, 600)

    i_x = property(fget=_get_x, fset=_set_x)
    s_grab = property(fget=_get_grab, fset=_set_grab)


# Main code
#==========
if __name__ == '__main__':
    o_progbar = GfxRect()
```

**UPDATE:** Moving the initialisation of the parent class in the child class after the internal properties seems to fix the problem which it's even more weird for me.

Before (doesn't work)

```
def __init__(self):
    print '--- START GfxObject initialisation'
    super(GfxRect, self).__init__()
    print '+++ END GfxObject initialisation'

    self._i_x = 0
    self._s_grab = 'nw'
    self._o_rect = None

    self._update_rect()
```

After (works)

```
def __init__(self):
    self._i_x = 0
    self._s_grab = 'nw'
    self._o_rect = None

    print '--- START GfxObject initialisation'
    super(GfxRect, self).__init__()
    print '+++ END GfxObject initialisation'

    self._update_rect()
```

...but something wrong seems to be happening under the hood. If I add `print 'child class "_update_rect" called'` to the `_update_rect` method, I get this output when running the script:

```
--- START GfxObject initialisation
child class "_update_rect" called  <-- ERROR!?
child class "_update_rect" called  <-- ERROR!?
+++ END GfxObject initialisation
child class "_update_rect" called  <-- this is correct
...
```

Which means the parent class is calling the child methods when being initialised!?

**UPDATE 2:** It seems this is the workflow when initialising the child class.

```
[1] Child.__init__()
[2] Parent.__init__()
[3] self.i_x = 0
[4] Child._set_x(0)
[5] Child._update_rect()
[6] Child._s_grab = 'foo'
```

The problem appears in step [6] because `._s_grab` attribute hasn't been created yet since the initialisation of the Child class is still initialising the Parent class. To me, it's counter-intuitive (and I would say that it's even a bug) the step [3]-[4] when setting the attribute `.i_x` of the Parent class triggers the property of the Child class.

By moving the initialisation of the parent class at the end of the child class or adding the missing attribute as a Parent class global (not to the instances), the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to initialise non-existing class properties/variables (you're calling `self.i_x`, but you've initialised `self._i_x`, for example) with a method call.

Changing GfxObject to:

```
class GfxObject(object):
    """
    Generic Graphical Object which is the parent class of all the sub-classes below.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._i_x = 0
        self._i_y = 0
        self._s_grab = 'nw'
```

Executed script on my machine. Result output:

> ```
> $ python2 issue.py 
> --- START GfxObject initialisation
> +++ END GfxObject initialisation
> <GfxRect>
>   .i_x:     0
>   ._i_x:    0
>   .s_grab:  nw
>   ._s_grab: nw
> ```

***EDIT***

Funny thing, once I moved `i_x` and `s_grab` from `GfxObject()`'s init, your code worked as a charm. Basically I only changed that class to this:

```
class GfxObject(object):
    """
    Generic Graphical Object which is the parent class of all the sub-classes below.
    """
    i_x = None
    s_grab = None
    def __init__(self):
    #    self.i_x = None
    #    self.s_grab = None
        #self.s_grab = 'nw'
        pass
```

So, it seems that you're expperiencing same issue I had with Python3 and `@property` decorator - if I didn't set an object to `None` or some other value before defining it as a property, it threw no attribute/not defined errors first time I'd try to use that getter/setter.

Comment: Two comments: 1) The parent class should only contain `i_x` property. It is in the subclass where I need to add the `_i_x` in order to bridge and manipulate that one. 2) The child class should inherit `i_x` from the parent (and then later I override it with my own code `i_x = property(fget=_get_x, fset=_set_x`

Comment: Funny thing is that your code worked perfectly the moment I've moved `i_x` and `s_grab` out of GfxObjects's init.

Comment: See the second update. I think I found the explanation to the problem and it explains our results when modifying the code. IMHO it's a bug or at least counter-intuitive behaviour (I cannot think about any situation where it's beneficial that the initialisation of the parent class triggers the methods of the child class).

Comment: Yes, it seems quite counter-intuitive. Probably best way to avoid having this issue is to either define all properties before `__init__()` call, together with their private objects, or in it. It seems that any other way doesn't work, neither with `@property` decorator nor `property()` method.

Comment: As a workaround I defined the attributes in the parent class as private with setters/getters and property. Not very pythonic but the code is more clear and it works.